# Negative value for moment.diff

Tags: angular, momentjs

I am getting negative value for moment().diff. I want to get number of seconds between now and past.

```
var now = moment();
var past = moment("2021-03-23T09:38:05Z"); //past time
var timeLapsed= now.diff(past);
Logger.debug(timeLapsed) //-3219879
```

I have searched a lot and could not find any solution. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: `2021-03-23T09:38:05Z` is future time. Because `Z` means UTC.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation points to give a simple comment, I have to go through the answer. Sorry!
But, I just wanted to say that I reproduced exactly the same code as it is in the question except that with **React.js** instead of **Angular**, and instead of *Logger* I used `console.log` and the **moment.js** gave me positive number.
Like this:

```
var now = moment();
var past = moment("2021-03-23T09:38:05Z");
var timeLapsed= now.diff(past);
console.log(timeLapsed) // 765040
```